# How to show only the name instead of the email address of the sender in a simple php mail script

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a simple php mail script which will send emails.

The problem is while sending it is displaying  `sendername <senderemail@domain.com>`

I have given in the code as `$headers = "From: $name <$senderEmail>";`

I want to display only name and not email address of the sender.

How do I do that?

Here is the program in its entirety.

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient=$_POST["senderemail"];
    $subject=$_POST["subject"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["email"];
    $city=$_POST["city"];
    $headers = "From: $name <$senderEmail>";
    $mailBody="$city\n";
    $process=explode(",",$recipient);
    reset($process);

    foreach ($process as $to) {
        mail($to,$subject, $mailBody,$headers);
    }

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your Message has been sent.</p>";
    echo 'Thank you! Your Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A From header containing both name and address should be formatted like this:

```
From: User Name <user@example.com>
```

If you don't provide a name, it will display the email address.

PHPMailer has built-in support for creating this header correctly for you via the `From` and `FromName` properties, and the `setFrom` method (it doesn't matter which you use):

```
$mail->setFrom('user@example/com', 'User Name');
```

or

```
$mail->From = 'user@example/com';
$mail->FromName = 'User Name';
```

Comment: Yes. You are correct about PHPMailer. But i am using a normal default php mail() function. Can't we do using this.

Comment: Yes you can, but it's much, much more difficult to make it work correctly. You're very likely to make a mess of it - especially given that you're already having trouble with just this simple header.

Answer (score 2):

Your generated message already seems to contain the user's full name in the `From:` header (assuming `$name` is the human-readable name).  How this is displayed by any individual user agent is no longer in your hands.  Very often, it will display both parts regardless; or only shorten to the human-readable name if the sender's email address is in the recipient's address book.  (Thunderbird takes this a step further and displays the information *from* the address book rather than the actual information in the message!)

One common problem is if the generated message has a different `Sender:` header; often, this will cause the recipient's user agent to display more than just the usual full name.  Your question doesn't mention this, nor does it show one of the generated messages; but perhaps this will help you find a solution.